# How to insert an index of a list inside the parenthesis of a method inside a second list (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

I am trying to insert a integer from a number list inside of a command in a separate command list (in python 3).

Since, for example, the print command in python 3 requires a (), how do I get the number (from the number list) inside of the () for the print command (from the command list).

I want to make a new list combining certain indexes from List One and List Two. For example, how would I put the number "10" (numLst index = 3) into the parenthesis of the command "print()" (cmdLst index = 1)?

List One (cmdLst)

1. "insert()"
2. "print()"
3. "remove()"
4. "append()"

List Two (numLst)

1. 0
2. 5
3. 1
4. 10
5. 0
6. 6
7. 6

This is the code I have attempted using, but it just appends the number to the end of the command like "print()10"

```
newLst.index(i).append(cmdLst.index(i) + numLst.index(i)
```

How can I solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [1]: cmd_list = ['insert({})', 'print({})', 'remove({})', 'append({})']

In [2]: num_list = [0, 5, 1, 10, 0, 6, 6]

In [3]: new_list = []

In [4]: new_list.append(cmd_list[1].format(num_list[3]))

In [5]: new_list
Out[5]: ['print(10)']
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a bit, I'm thinking you may be off in your approach to the solution as it seems like you may be creating too many lists to capture the data you are trying to manipulate using lists, which is forcing you to iterate over too many lists variables and nested condition statements and is now causing you to try to attempt to slice a built in python method in order to execute it correctly within the python 3 environment.

Based on what I think you are doing, I think you need to work on the style and efficiency of your code in order to write a program that will solve your problem a bit more elegantly.

Instead of trying to iterate over every command, try to capture ALL ofthe data you need into a list in order to validate the input you will be working with in order to manipulate the data you need to work with as soon as you capture said data. Once you have the data your problem may be as easy as type casting the data and executing the method you need as soon as you capture it using one loop, one condition and a minimal amount of variables which will effectively decrease the amount of memory you allocate to deal with your problem.

I went on hackerRank and found a problem that seemed to match what you are trying to do and maybe this example can help you out in a way that will help you understand what I mean when I say that maybe you just need to work on the style of your program.

See the code below and see if you can understand where I am coming from and how you may be able to use the concept of capturing and manipulating your data as early as you possibly can within the program. You may be able to improve you program's efficiency by eliminating a list() or two by reducing some of the variables you have to create in memory so that as soon as you capture the data you can just execute the method you need instead of trying to do something as ridiculous as slicing a method just to input a string of data that you need to work with.

Check it out and let me know if it helps:

```
n = int(input().rstrip())
cmdLst = list()
numLst = list()

for i in range(n):
    cmdLst.append(input().split())
    if(cmdLst[i][0] == "insert"):
        numLst.insert(int(cmdLst[i][1]),int(cmdLst[i][2]))
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "print"):
        print(numLst)
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "remove"):
        numLst.remove(int(cmdLst[i][1]))
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "append"):
        numLst.append(int(cmdLst[i][1]))
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "sort"):
        numLst.sort()
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "pop"):
        numLst.pop()
    elif(cmdLst[i][0] == "reverse"):
        numLst.reverse()
```

good luck!